# Does different delay in C++ code affects UDP timing for communication?

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, udp, latency

I am trying to measure the latency of communication between a linux machine and a NVIDIA jetson tk1.On the jetson side I created 2 UDP sockets on two different ports. First it waits for a message (an integer) from linux machine using recvfrom() in non blocking mode and then does some image processing on the GPU and finally send a message (again array of integer) to the linux machine. Below is the code on the JetsonTK1 side:

```
int buf1[20];
while (true)
{
    frame=frame+1;
    while(1)
    {   
        n=recvfrom(sockfd2, buf1, 20, MSG_DONTWAIT,(struct sockaddr *) &clientaddr, &clientlen);
        if(n>0){
            gettimeofday(&tp1, NULL);
            break;
        }
    }

    ////////////////////////////
    /*  Do some image processing 
    This part takes 3ms*/
    ///////////////////////////

    int POS[2]={frame,22};
    numbytes = sendto(sockfd, &POS, sizeof(POS), MSG_DONTWAIT, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen);
    gettimeofday(&tp2, NULL);
    unsigned long msR=1000000*(tp2.tv_sec-tp1.tv_sec)+(tp2.tv_usec-tp1.tv_usec);
    cout<<msR<<endl;
}
```

On the linux machine side I have the following:

```
int buf1[20];
while(1)
{
    int A=1;

    //usleep(1000);
    usleep(1000000);

    int POS[2]={1,1};
    sendto(sockfd,  &A, sizeof(A), MSG_DONTWAIT, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen);

    gettimeofday(&tp1R,NULL);
    while(1)
    {
        n=recvfrom(sockfd2, buf1, 20, MSG_DONTWAIT,(struct sockaddr *) &clientaddr, &clientlen);
        if(n>0){
            gettimeofday(&tp2R,NULL);
            unsigned long msR= 1000000*(tp2R.tv_sec-tp1R.tv_sec)+(tp2R.tv_usec-tp1R.tv_usec) ;
            cout<<buf1[0]<<" "<<buf1[1]<<" "<<msR<<endl;    
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

All the measurements are done using `gettimeofday()` function in C++. As you can see I have a delay on the linux machine side `usleep()` of 1 second.Basically the linux machine sends a message to JetsonTK1 to capture an image and do the processing and finally it receives a message from the Jetson that image processing is done for this frame and then a delay and repeating the same procedure.I am measuring the timing from the moment a packet is sent from linux machine until it receives a confirmation that processing is done.   When calculating the timing on both side with this 1 second delay the latency is above 11ms. However when I change the delay from 1 seconds to 100ms in usleep() the timing I get in both side is 3ms which is equivalent to the timing for the image processing on the JetsonTK1 side. How and why does this happen? what does this delay have to do with latency from send to receive in UDP sockets? I also tried to use a blocking mode of receiving but it didnt change anything... Does this have to do something with GPU processing?

I know these delays are somehow related to CPU scheduler but that works in scale of nanoseconds and a simple UDP message should not take 11ms to arrive...

Comment: Not related directly to your question, but do keep in mind that UDP packet delivery is *not* guaranteed and if one is dropped in transit you will not be told.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: Yes I know that and I can check if the data has arrived, the delay between arrivals are 1 second and also in low delays I count the number of send packets so I am fine with that.

Comment: Btw; You may be interested in [ENet](http://enet.bespin.org).

Comment: As a guess, when the code for UDP recv in the kernel is waiting for a packet to be read so it can wake up the calling process again, there's no checks to see if the socket has been closed locally (It would check *before* that point, but not during). Use `poll()`/etc. with a timeout instead of a blocking `recv()`?

Comment: Might be instructive to run `wireshark` to capture packets between the two machines. I'm wondering if an ARP cache is being flushed or something. But if nothing else, you can find out whether `wireshark` is seeing roughly the same time delta between request and response packets.